# Tasks list: Workflow action: Create New List item

Tags: workflow, 2007

Within my workflow using SPD I am using the "Create New Item" action to create a new Task list item this is fired when a holidayrequest item is created.

My problem is I cannot see how to create/store a link back to the orignial holiday request item that created the task, so I can display this in the Task's edit form.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of a question you posted last week at http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/3269/creating-a-related-item-link-in-task-list-using-a-workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When assigning the values to the newly created task, when specifying the field that will hold the URL, click the 'fx' button to carry out a workflow lookup.

Select 'Current Item' as the source and 'Source URL' as the field.

Comment: Thanks, from the 'Current Item' I have the choice of 'Server Relative URL' and 'URL Path'. Looks like 'URL Path' will work.